# SMB/CIFS protocol for iOS

Tags: smb, cifs

Does anyone know library to browse (and upload/download/stream) on smb shares (SMB/CIFS protocol) from iOS. This must be support for all the Windows OS. This is grade help for me.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite an answer to your question, but I have some tips:

1. If you write your own client, don't trust the IETF RFC. Microsoft
   hasn't been scrupulous in its adherence to the spec. And be sure to
   test with Unicode file/folder names, all major versions of Windows,
   and so on.
2. Don't write your own client. :-)
3. If you use an open-source library, make sure it's not GPL or LGPL,
   unless you plan to open-source your entire project. LGPL almost
   works—it does on Mac OS X—but it requires dynamic linking, which
   isn't supported on iOS.
4. You may see apps in the app store that use GPL or LGPL libraries,
   but don't assume that it is safe to use them yourself. Those apps
   are often blatantly abusing the license.
5. opensource.apple.com has an smb client that's a great reference but
   it's a file system kernel extension, so you can't use it directly.